# How can I prevent Python from exiting on database connection failure?

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling

I have been trying to write a script to test if connection to a certain mysql DB is possible.

If it is possible it should give a "OK" Output and if not It is suppose to say "FAIL" and carry on with operation.

It works fine when connection is available.
But when the connection fails to connect the script gets exited giving an error

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'yoda'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

But this interferes from script doing rest of the process

I called it like

```
if not db.connect(UnivConf['DBHT'],UnivConf['DBUN'],UnivConf['DBPW'],UnivConf['DBDB'])
```

How can I solve this problem and get the script to continue on without quitting

Comment: Why don't you put it inside a `try ... except` block?

Comment: why should the script continue? if you don't have a valid DB connection, then any other db code later on is going to fail anyways. basically "my car just exploded. how can I keep driving down the highway anyways?"

Comment: I need to log database server status at regular times,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [try](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
try:
    if not db.connect(UnivConf['DBHT'],UnivConf['DBUN'],UnivConf['DBPW'],UnivConf['DBDB'])
        # Do something

except _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError as e:
    print "Caught an exception : " + str(e.message)
    print "Something blah blah..."

finally:
    print "Done"
```

Comment: For completeness, I would add `else:`

Comment: @JakubM. for completeness of your comment, what would you put in the `else` (I actually want to know :o)

Comment: The answer for the OP question is a basic Python concept, so for educational purposes, I would add a full `try/except/else/finally` example. But probably this comment is educational enough :)

Comment: You can remove the 'if' completely. The try/except catches db connection failures. Its not right in any case, because it does not save the connection object which you need to do anything useful.